# Export parquet file schema to JSON or CSV

Tags: pyspark, schema, metadata, parquet

I need to extract schema of parquet file into JSON, TXT or CSV format.
That should include column name, datatype from parquet file.

For example:

```
{"id", "type" : "integer" },
 {"booking_date""type" : "timestamp", "format" : "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f" }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can read the `schema` from the `parquet` file using `.schema` and convert to **`json`** format finally save as **`textfile`**.

**`input parquet file:`**

```
spark.read.parquet("/tmp").printSchema()
 #root
 #|-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 #|-- name: string (nullable = true)
 #|-- booking_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

---

**`Extract the schema and write to HDFS/local filesystem:`**

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize( #converting from string to rdd
[spark.read.parquet("/tmp").schema.json()] #read schema of parquetfile
 ).repartition(1).\
saveAsTextFile("/tmp_schema/") #saving the file into HDFS
```

---

**`Read the output file from hdfs:`**

```
$ hdfs dfs -cat /tmp_schema/part-00000
{"fields":[{"metadata":{},"name":"id","nullable":true,"type":"integer"},{"metadata":{},"name":"name","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"booking_date","nullable":true,"type":"timestamp"}],"type":"struct"}
```